# swift NSCollectionView layout wrong after window resize

Tags: swift, macos, nscollectionview

I have a NSCollectionView using sections and flow layout.  Initial layout is fine but resizing the window causes the vertical position of the collection view items to move (relative to the top window boundary).  The section breaks stay stationary relative to the top window boundary (good).  But the items moving up causes them to overlap with the sections and eventually move up out of the window area as I decrease the height of the window.

[image]

[image]

I think this is related to how the mac uses the bottom as the origin of the coordinates.  Resizing the window causes the bottom window boundary to move.

For reference here's where I configure my collection view, including standard flow layout.

```
    fileprivate func configureCollectionView() {
    let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: "MonitorViewItem", bundle: nil)
    mapCollectionView.register(nib, forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("MonitorViewItem"))
    let flowLayout = NSCollectionViewFlowLayout()
    flowLayout.itemSize = NSSize(width: 100.0, height: 40.0)
    flowLayout.sectionInset = NSEdgeInsets(top: 25.0, left: 10.0, bottom: 10.0, right: 10.0)
    flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 10.0
    flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 10.0
    mapCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout

}
```

I tried invalidating the layout in my window resizing delegate function.  My print statement confirms its being called as the window resizes, but invalidating the layout is not solving the issue.

```
extension MapWindowController: NSWindowDelegate {
    func windowDidResize(_ notification: Notification) {
        print("got resize")
        mapCollectionView.collectionViewLayout!.invalidateLayout()
    }
}
```

So far I have not attempted to subclass my view and override isFlipped.

Here's my window hierarchy in my .xib:

```
Window
  View
    Bordered Scroll View - Collection View
       Clip View
          Map Collection view
             Collection View Flow layout
          scroller
          scroller
```

Any suggestions to fix the collection view item vertical positions as the nswindow is resized?